# IE8 Browser JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, png

Can anyone tell me the reason why the following works in IE8 but not in Safari 5.1?

```
<a onclick="javascript:submit();"><img src="Images/Next.png" width="20" height="20"></a>
```

JavaScript is enabled in both IE8 and Safari 5.1.

Comment: Error?? `javascript:` label is useless there.

Comment: Don't edit your question and remove the question!  Why would you do that?

Answer (score 3):

Try dropping the 'javascript:' from the onclick.  The only time I see this syntax used is when it is in the href.   The content of onclick is assumed to be JavaScript by default.  As such,

```
javascript:submit();
```

Is not valid JavaScript.